# Play, Websocket: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

Tags: java, websocket, playframework-2.0

I'm new to the Play framework, and Play's docs are not comprehensive

I'm trying to write test websocket with help of this docs:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaWebSockets

Controller

```
package controllers.websockets;

import akka.actor.ActorSystem;
import akka.stream.Materializer;
import play.libs.streams.ActorFlow;
import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.WebSocket;

import javax.inject.Inject;

public class TestWebSocketController extends Controller {

    private final ActorSystem actorSystem;
    private final Materializer materializer;

    @Inject
    public TestWebSocketController(ActorSystem actorSystem, Materializer materializer) {
        this.actorSystem = actorSystem;
        this.materializer = materializer;
    }

    public WebSocket socket() {
        return WebSocket.Text.accept(request ->
                ActorFlow.actorRef(TestWebSocketActor::props,
                        actorSystem, materializer
                )
        );
    }
}
```

Actor:

```
package controllers.websockets;

import akka.actor.AbstractActor;
import akka.actor.ActorRef;
import akka.actor.Props;

public class TestWebSocketActor extends AbstractActor {
    public static Props props(ActorRef out) {
        return Props.create(TestWebSocketActor.class, out);
    }

    private final ActorRef out;

    public TestWebSocketActor(ActorRef out) {
        this.out = out;
    }

    @Override
    public AbstractActor.Receive createReceive() {
        return receiveBuilder()
                .match(String.class, message ->
                        out.tell("I received your message: " + message, self())
                )
                .build();
    }
}
```

conf/routes:

```
# WebSockets
GET           /ws           controllers.websockets.TestWebSocketController.socket()
```

I'm trying to connect with help of Simmple WebSocket Plugin for Chrome, https://www.websocket.org/echo.html, with such url: ws://localhost:9000/ws , but error message is appeared:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:9000/ws' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404 
CLOSED: ws://localhost:9000/ws
```